# How to Import Bookmarks to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Nothing happens when I import bookmarks.

Add bookmarks to Chrome

On your computer, open Chrome.

At the top right, click More More.

Select Bookmarks and then Bookmark Manager.

At the top right, click More More and then Import Bookmarks.

Select the program that contains the bookmarks you'd like to import.

Click Import and then Done.

Bookmarks were not imported. Google Toolbar extension is no longer available.